# insertar datos al inicio en un campo ya creado en sql

Tags: sql

me pueden ayudar indicandome como se realiza la actualizaciòn de datos al incio sobre un campo ya creado en SQL por ejemplo:

telefono
323890988
247639087

Para los campos de la tabla telefono requiero agregar al inicio de cada uno de ellos el valor 012 quedando:

012323890988
012247639087

Tener en cuenta con son millones de datos a actualizar.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE tabla SET [columna] = '012' + RTRIM([columna])
```

Utilizamos el [operador de concatenación de cadenas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) para agregar el valor ¨012¨ al inicio de la cadena y [RTRIM](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/sql/t-sql/functions/rtrim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) para obtener el valor de la cadena sin espacios.

No olvides usar un `WHERE` si es que aplica